# How can I find internal overlaps in my polygon feature class ideally via modelbuilder tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, modelbuilder, geometry, overlapping-features

I have a polygon layer containing "depth curves" for the making of a skin of earth kind of map. I want to check whether or not my feature class contain any overlaps internally between these polygons.
What kind of tools can I use for this? Ideally i would like to end up with a feature class containing the bits of overlaps, so i have the possibility to check graphically where my features overlaps. And if I could somehow implement this in a larger model, things would really look good.

Comment: Actually something like this guy who uses a plugin "ET Geo Wizards" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzH5Ht7KmyM) and lets the wizard create the overlapping features. I want to do this in a model:-)

Comment: Have you looked on the ESRI gallery, a quick search on the word overlap throws are several tools you can download for free and use. Look [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=overlap&t=content&focus=tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt if your single polygon feature class contains self-overlapping polygons, and when this constitutes an error in your final product, you could run the intersect tool. I didn't know that the tool itself could handle a single input, but it turned out that it works in precisely the same way which it would have done when analyzing multiple inputs. [Link to ArcGIS Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000). It's a fairly easy way to get a graphic view of "geometric" errors in your layers. Like the image below where the scraped area symbolizes an internal overlap within a single polygon feature class which in this case represent an unsurveyed area at sea.

[image: Scraped area symbolizes an internal overlap in a single feature class which in this case represent an unsurveyed area at sea]